# Javascript not printing variable as expected

Tags: javascript, json

For the following javascript

```
for (i = 0; i < agentIds.length; i++) {
        var agentId = agentIds[i];
        var variable1 = "isWrapup_"+agentId;
        alert(variable1);
        var text2 = "var isWrapup = JSON.parse(${"+variable1+"});";
        alert(text2);
}
```

The first alert is printed as: `isWrapup_efdbf4e71c9c6997eb705a71a6819b78`

The second alert is printed as : `var isWrapup = JSON.parse('+variable1+');`

I'm expecting to print it as : `var isWrapup = JSON.parse('isWrapup_efdbf4e71c9c6997eb705a71a6819b78')`

What have I done wrong here?

Comment: are we missing some Escape characters?

Comment: Try: `var text2 = \`var isWrapup = JSON.parse(${variable1});\`;`

Answer (score 0):

The text formatting needs to be corrected, concat works better in these situations, [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/90203/why-is-so-bad-for-concatenation) is why. Try:

```
for (i = 0; i < agentIds.length; i++) {
        var agentId = agentIds[i];
        var variable1 = "isWrapup_"+agentId;
        alert(variable1);
        var str1 = "var isWrapup = JSON.parse(${"
        var str2 = "});"
        var text2 = str1.concat(variable1,str2);;
        alert(text2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do currently is remove that '$' from the the picture and thats it.

```
var text2 = "var isWrapup = JSON.parse({" + variable1 + "});";  // works fine here : https://www.javascript.com/try
```

Also, you are unintentionally using an [Escape_character#JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character#JavaScript)

> The Point-to-Point Protocol uses the 0x7D octet (\175, or ASCII: } )
>   as an escape character

In which case you can try something like this in your code :

```
var text2 = "var isWrapup = JSON.parse({{" + variable1 + "}});";
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: its print : var isWrapup = JSON.parse([ + variable1 + ]);